# Why the code does not work?

Tags: php

The issue is within the MySQL connect and query part (first part worked):

```
<?php
$param=$_GET['m'];
$param=str_replace("-", " ", $param);
$param=ucwords($param); 
echo $param; 
$host="localhost";
$username="user_name";
$password="password_here";
$database_name="database_name_here";
$link=mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database_name');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$query=$mysqli_query($link, "SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE another_column_name='$param'");
echo $query; 
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I get the following error:

> "Connect failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'host' (20)"

...and the code is correct according to PhpCodeChecker.com.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. It looks like you have passed the string `'host'` into `mysqli_connect(...)`. Try passing in `$host` with the `$host` variable set to your real host above.

Comment: Update `mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database_name');` into `mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database_name);`

Comment: You are passing strings instead of variables to `mysqli_connect()`. Use `mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database_name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
$link=mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database_name');
```

should be:

```
 $link=mysqli_connect($host,$username$,$password,$database_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection line to

```
$link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database_name);
```

Use the actual connection names for $username, $password, $database_name.

Answer (score 0):

Change connection statement like this:

```
 $link=mysqli_connect($host,$username$,$password,$database_name);
```

Ansd also Change the mysql query execution like this. Remove **$**.

```
$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE another_column_name='$param'"); // bad practice
```

Use bind param instead of using the parameter directly inside query. Try this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE another_column_name= ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
```

You should use

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database_name);
```

Also make sure that `$host`, `$username`, `$password` and `$database_name` are set with the correct values.

Good luck